# How to find a module's location

Tags: ruby

I am in a situation that n a gem `foo_bar` that I have written, and which I use as follows:

```
require 'foo_bar'
include FooBar
```

suddendly, a constant `Baz` appeared:

```
defined? Baz #=> :constant
Baz.class #=> Module
```

I forgot where did I define `Baz`. If it had any instance methods, I could use `#source_location` method to find the file where I defined `Baz`. But it has none:

```
Baz.instance_methods #=> []
```

How do I find in which file (or where) a module that popped up in my top namespace is defined?

**Additional addmission and finding:** The constant I am talking about is `Net`, and its appearance is not tied to `include FooBar`, but to another line, `require` of my gem `sy` (http://gihub.com/boris-s/sy), which you can install by `gem install sy`. By stepping the gem (https://github.com/boris-s/sy/blob/master/lib/sy.rb), I found that none of the require lines, or the top lines up to the `module SY` line does not trigger `Net` appearance. The `module SY` definition does.

**Furthermore**, I found the pragmatic answer `Net` is `Net` as in `Net::HTTP`. The authors didn't assume that someone would be working with other kinds of nets than internets, and I didn't think about `Net::HTTP`, because I was working with Petri nets and defining my own `Net` classes. Although I solved my practical problem, it is still interesting to find the general answer of finding modules' sources.

Comment: I don't know the answer yet, but the good news is, if you're using MRI Ruby, the source location is definitely stored. The definition of the function `rb_const_set` includes the following lines:

    `ce = ALLOC(rb_const_entry_t);`
    `MEMZERO(ce, rb_const_entry_t, 1);`
    `ce->flag = visibility;`
    `ce->line = rb_sourceline();`

Comment: It appears that it's stored so that it can be called back in the `"previous definition of %s was here"` warning, but I'm struggling to get that warning to actually appear right now. I just keep getting only `"already initialized constant %s"`.

Comment: Nice question, let me try also.

Comment: You also could try `methods` instead of `instance_methods`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming a file is loaded you can do:

```
$LOADED_FEATURES.select { |file| File.read(file).include?('module Foo') rescue false }
```

Comment: A fine pragmatic solution, I am forced to accept it =). You taught me a good example of use of `$LOADED_FEATURES` global variable.

Comment: The gem covers some other uses cases such as name spacing. Its not too complex, so if this one-liner doesn't meet your needs, take a look at the contents of the gem. https://github.com/jwaldrip/modloc/blob/master/lib/modloc/core_ext/module.rb

Comment: Took a look. I think that that concept will be useful also for other things than just locating modules. But let me note that it's not all-powerful and obfuscated cases can be imagined defeating it. But it's very good.

Comment: That's no better than grep, and there are ways to create a module that will defeat this method.

Answer (score 10):

> .. a constant Baz appeared .. I forgot where did I define Baz.

Ruby 2.7 added `const_source_location`.

```ruby
Object.const_source_location('Baz')
#=> ["/../app/models/baz.rb", 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment you could also use [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to find a module's path:

```
$LOADED_FEATURES.grep(/module_name/)
```